# jquery chart plugin that support udf keys

Tags: python, highcharts

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[{'a':1,'b':2},{'a':3,'b':4}...]
```

and, is there any jquery chart plugin that supports user defined x keys and y keys?
like this:

```
{
xAxis: 'a',
yAxis: ['b', 'c'...],
data: [{'a':1,'b':2},{'a':3,'b':4}...]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

l1 = [{'a':1,'b':2},{'a':3,'b':4}]

res = defaultdict(list)

for i in l1:
    for k, v in i.items():
        res[k].append(v)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2, 4]})
```